# strlen from C to assembly, why do processor make these steps?

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, stack, x86-64

I was studying the assembly code of this C function:

```
int stringlen(char *s1, char *s2) {
    int result = 0; 
    int i = 0; 
    while (s1[i] != 0) {
        result++; 
        i++; 
    }
    int j = 0; 
    while (s2[j] != 0) {
        result++; 
        j++; 
    }
    return result; 
}

int main(void) {
    char s1[] = "this is "; 
    char s2[] = "a test"; 
    int result = stringlen(s1, s2); 
    return 0; 
}
```

based on assembly code, on "LN3" I have,

```
$LN3:
    push    rbp
    push    rsi
    push    rdi
    sub     rsp, 336                ; 00000150H
    lea     rbp, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    lea     rdi, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    mov     ecx, 28
    mov     eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep     stosd
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR __security_cookie
    xor     rax, rbp
    mov     QWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[rbp], rax
    lea     rcx, OFFSET FLAT:__EFF96FC6_main@c
    call    __CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode
```

this is related to `main` function.

first question:

- why do I have to subtract `336` from `rsp`?

then, I know that `lea` is used to save an address to make coding easier (because working with pointer may bring to errors easily), and I know that `QWORD` means quadword and it simply means 4 bytes (i.e, = 32 bits).

second question:

- why do I have to save the same address (at `rsp + 32`) both in `rbp` and in `rdi`?

last 2 questions:

I think I know that `ecx` register is usually used to save the dimension of an array or string, but

- why do I have to move `28` to `ecx`? similarly,
- why do I have to move `-858993460` to `eax`? are these 2 numbers always the same? or do they change based on the function I create? if they change, how can I know which number move in these registers? is there a way to compute them?

Comment: you don't have to. This is what the compiler does. It looks like the part you quoted is extra safety checks, not your actual code.

Comment: so this is not assembly?

Comment: obviously it's assembly

Comment: I've thought the extra safety check is only in this command: " __CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode "

Comment: No, the compiler also reserves a bunch of extra stack space you don't need and fills it with CCCCCCCC... pattern. Presumably when the function returns, it makes sure it still has CCCCCCC... and if not then it will display an error message (buffer overflow) and crash.

Comment: are you referring to this line? mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH

Comment: that line puts that number into the eax register

Comment: Looks like an MSVC debug build, which "poisons" some extra stack space with `0xCC` bytes to help you detect reads of uninitialized variables, and out-of-bounds reads.  It's using `rep stosd` as a `memset`.   I assume this code is from `main`, since that's the function that has some local arrays.

Comment: This is assembly generated as part of the [buffer security check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check?view=msvc-170). If you want to study assembly output of your code, you should take a careful look at all the compiler options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assembly output you posted is unrelated to your code: it seems to be a prologue generated by the Microsoft compiler as part of their [security enhancements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check?view=msvc-170). Unless you are interested in this specific subject, you can disregard this code and focus on actual assembly code generated for your program.

You can do this very effectively with [Godbolt's online Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/raTbbeP6h)

You can test different compilers and options.

On the linked page, you will notice that the **clang** compiler with optimisations enabled produced just 2 instructions for the `main` function, as it determined that the function call had no side effects and the return value was not used.

In the `stringlen` function, it generates an instruction `lea rax,[rax + 1]` to increment `rax` instead of `inc rax` or `add rax,1` to avoid updating the flags that are tested at the following instruction `jne .LBB0_7`.

Answer (score 0):

Can be translated something like this. I am new in assembly too.

By the way `QWORD` is 8 byte and `DWORD` is 4 byte.

```
main :
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 32
    movabs  rax, 2338328219631577204          ; arbitrary value moved to rax
    mov     QWORD PTR[rbp - 13], rax          ; first 8 char in s1
    mov     BYTE PTR[rbp - 5], 0              ; null byte terminator of s1
    mov     DWORD PTR[rbp - 20], 1702109281   ; first 4 byte of s2  
    mov     DWORD PTR[rbp - 17], 7631717      ; last 3 byte of s2 including null byte
    lea     rdx, [rbp - 20]                   ; s1 decays to char pointer, rdx holds it s1[0] address 
    lea     rax, [rbp - 13]                   ; s2 decays to char pointer, rax holds it s2[0] address            
    mov     rsi, rdx                          ; move s1[0]'s address to rsi  
    mov     rdi, rax                          ; move s2[0]'s address to rdi  
    call    stringlen                           
    mov     DWORD PTR[rbp - 4], eax           ; get return value from function, put it in int variable 
    mov     eax, 0                            ; put 0 to eax, eax will be return value from main()  
stringlen:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     QWORD PTR[rbp - 24], rdi          ; move s1's address to char pointer(8 byte)
    mov     QWORD PTR[rbp - 32], rsi          ; move s2's address to char pointer(8 byte)
    // no 7 byte differences between [rbp - 13] && [rbp - 20] like in main()
    mov     DWORD PTR[rbp - 4], 0             ; move 0 to int variable (int result)
    mov     DWORD PTR[rbp - 8], 0             ; move 0 to int variable (int i)   
    jmp.L2
.L3:
    add     DWORD PTR[rbp - 4], 1             ; increase result++
    add     DWORD PTR[rbp - 8], 1             ; increase i++
.L2 :
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR[rbp - 8]           ; move (int i) to eax // firstLoop[int i = 0]
    movsx   rdx, eax                          ; move sign extended eax to rdi  
    // that integer(int i) can be used as negative too (that is why sign extend i guess)
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR[rbp - 24]          ; move s1's address to rax 
    add     rax, rdx                          ; (ptr + 0) // pointer aritmetics rax = s1[0]'s address
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR[rax]                ; get s[0] first char of s1[](char array) zero extend to eax
    // zero extending says that i will be used as unsigned char 
    // that 1 byte will be used from 0 to 255 for ASCII Values
    test    al, al                            ; bitwise AND operation && s[i] && s[i] == 0 ZF set 
    // if ZF set je will be chosen else jne.L3 will be chosen
    // loop begins 
    jne.L3                                  
    // when int i's value become 8 which s[8] == '\0' it will get out of the loop and continiues
    mov     DWORD PTR[rbp - 12], 0            ; move 0 to int variable (result)
    jmp.L4
.L5:
    add     DWORD PTR[rbp - 4], 1
    add     DWORD PTR[rbp - 12], 1
.L4 :
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR[rbp - 12]          
    movsx   rdx, eax                          
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR[rbp - 32]            
    add     rax, rdx
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR[rax]
    test    al, al
    jne.L5
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR[rbp - 4]           ; return (int result) to main() inside eax;
```